# Reports and data visualization with .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, graph, reporting, data-visualization

How can I create reports (like well-formatted pdf files) and analytical graphs with C#/.NET?

Are there native libraries for this purpose?

I use finaquant's table function [library](http://finaquant.com/products/finaquantcalcs) for table operations. I need to integrate some additional functionality to generate reports and send them to proper addresses by email.

Comment: you have not said what database, so i assume sql server http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964126(v=sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 5):

You can use rdlc or crystal reports for that. You can create well-formatted and complex reports with these reporting frameworks. By default it gives you functionality to export the data to excel, pdf and word. You can also use report viewer to view the data on a web page.

See below link for the tutorial on rdlc reports:

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/09/creating-an-asp-net-report-using-visual-studio-2010-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of reporting tools on the market. As Adarsh said you could try a free crystal reports, but if you need a higher level of customization and flexibility, there is a very good reporting tool [List and Label](http://www.combit.net/en/) which offers a .NET Api as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to program it yourself and you have access to the database, then you can use some third party reporting engines like [DBxtra](http://www.dbxtra.com/) which lets you email the reports automatically on an scheduled basis.